# Can I customize the format of error outputs of common lisp?

Tags: debugging, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm using SBCL. When something goes wrong in my program, SBCL will print a long list of back trace informations. This is annoying sometimes, and I have to scroll back and back to find out what the error message was. Can I customize the error outputs(e.g., shorten the back trace list)?

Comment: as far as i know you cannot configure the initial stacktrace but using the debugger loop might improve on some of the inconvieniences encountered http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Debugger , but you can disable the debugger completely ad try to manually step to the point where it crashes http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#toplevel

Comment: I would use something like Emacs/Slime, where the debugger appears in another buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some experimenting with sbcl:

```
(defun crash-big-stack (&optional (c 20))
       (if (= c 0)
           (error "crash boooooom")
                       (another-crash (- c 1))))

(defun another-crash (&optional c)
       (crash-big-stack c))
```

1) I am using SBCL 1.0.57.0 which wont give any stacktrace if not asked (using slime though will result in a stacktrace), the only scenario where sbcl crashes and prints the complete stacktrace is when you either use `(sb-ext:disable-debugger)` or provide the toplevel argument `sbcl --disable-debugger`

SBCL (without `(sb-ext:disable-debugger)`):

```
* (crash-big-stack)

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002978CA3}>:
  crash boooooom

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(CRASH-BIG-STACK 0)
0]
```

SBCL (with `(sb-ext:disable-debugger)`):

```
(crash-big-stack)
unhandled SIMPLE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                    {1002978CA3}>:
  crash boooooom

0: (SB-DEBUG::MAP-BACKTRACE
    #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN BACKTRACE) {100465352B}>
    :START
    0
    :COUNT
    128)
1: (BACKTRACE 128 #<SYNONYM-STREAM :SYMBOL SB-SYS:*STDERR* {1000169AE3}>)
2: (SB-DEBUG::DEBUGGER-DISABLED-HOOK
    #<SIMPLE-ERROR "crash boooooom" {1004651C23}>
    #<unavailable argument>)
3: (SB-DEBUG::RUN-HOOK
    *INVOKE-DEBUGGER-HOOK*
    #<SIMPLE-ERROR "crash boooooom" {1004651C23}>)
4: (INVOKE-DEBUGGER #<SIMPLE-ERROR "crash boooooom" {1004651C23}>)
5: (ERROR "crash boooooom")
6: (CRASH-BIG-STACK 0)
7: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (CRASH-BIG-STACK) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
8: (EVAL (CRASH-BIG-STACK))
9: (INTERACTIVE-EVAL (CRASH-BIG-STACK) :EVAL NIL)
10: (SB-IMPL::REPL-FUN NIL)
11: ((LAMBDA () :IN SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-REPL))
12: (SB-IMPL::%WITH-REBOUND-IO-SYNTAX
     #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA # :IN SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-REPL) {100450355B}>)
13: (SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-REPL NIL)
14: (SB-IMPL::TOPLEVEL-INIT)
15: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-236911 :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))
16: ((LABELS SB-IMPL::RESTART-LISP :IN SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE))

unhandled condition in --disable-debugger mode, quitting
```

As far as the SBCL manual goes, there is no way to influence the predefined behavior of the SBCL debugger interface, but [you can provide your own](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Debugger-Invocation) by setting `sb-ext:*invoke-debugger-hook*`

```
* (defun crash-big-stack (&optional (c 20))
       (if (= c 0)
           (error "crash boooooom")
           (let ((waste (another-crash (- c 1))))
         (+ waste 42))))

CRASH-BIG-STACK
* (defun another-crash (&optional c)
       (crash-big-stack c))

ANOTHER-CRASH
* (setf sb-ext:*invoke-debugger-hook* #'(lambda(&rest args) (sb-ext:exit)))

#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (&REST ARGS)) {10045CEF1B}>
* (crash-big-stack)
~:
```

Answer (score 2):

See: `*backtrace-frame-count*`.